# How to find second smallest from a set of formulas in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How to find **second smallest** of the following in Excel 2007 Sheet:

- `(M2+G2)/N2`
- `(N2+H2)/O2`
- `(O2+I2)/P2`
- `(P2+J2)/Q2`
- `(Q2+K2)/R2`

I tried the following, but it does not work.

```
=SMALL((M2+G2)/N2,(N2+H2)/O2,(O2+I2)/P2,(P2+J2)/Q2,(Q2+K2)/R2),2)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer from Excel community.  Hence sharing it here.

Please try (and confirm the formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=SMALL((M2:Q2+G2:K2)/N2:R2,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution is, of course, correct, but it uses a specific data layout.
If the data were randomly arranged, you could use this formula:

```
=SMALL(CHOOSE({1;2;3;4;5},(M2+G2)/N2,(N2+H2)/O2,(O2+I2)/P2,(P2+J2)/Q2,(Q2+K2)/R2),2)
```

This formula does not require `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.